# android select multiple items in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` and I want to select multiple items in the `ListView` without using `CheckedTextView`.

Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a CheckBox. All you need is a boolean flag on your list objects. When the user clicks an item you change the state of the flag, and probably the background or text color for that list item.

Comment: I already tried this before posting this question, but its not working i.e background and text color are not changing. could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it, but I would use `ListView` with checkbox but non visible.
Perform the `setChecked(True)` when the user press on an item.
I would also try changing the item background when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: i don't think you need a hidden checkbox view.  Just use a boolean.

Comment: how can one deal with Android's re-using of ListView items when scrolling to avoid ending up with the wrong object highlighted?

Comment: @finiteloop. Remember the 'else' :-)

Comment: @Glenn Bech I can't follow on your "else" hint. How does that prevent the ListView being recycled by the app, resulting in wrong items being selected?

Comment: @finiteloop me neither. My comment must be a reference to code, or some other info that was posted, but are now longer part of the question. :)